# Quit MS Access without compacting, even though "Auto Compact" is set

Tags: vba, ms-access

We have numerous MS Access files with the "Auto Compact" option set.
I would like to open a file using VBA and close it (or quit) without going through the long compacting process. However, I don't want to touch the "Auto Compact" option, because it needs to stay True for the normal users.

Is it possible to close the file with VBA and skip the compacting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always **disable the Auto Compact on Close** and use a Flagging system. Create a Universal flag, allowCompact As Boolean, and based on the user permission set the Flag to True, and on a Form (probably a hidden form) or the form that is always kept open's Close method you can check if the Compact Flag is set, if yes use the Code (http://access.mvps.org/access/general/gen0041.htm) to Perform Compact else just quit the DB.

```
'In a Standard Module
Public allowCompact

'Code to perform AutoComapct
Public Sub CompactDB()
   CommandBars("Menu Bar"). _
   Controls("Tools"). _
   Controls("Database utilities"). _
   Controls("Compact and repair database..."). _
   accDoDefaultAction
End Sub
```

Then in the Form that is opened first (probably a login Form)

```
Private Sub buttonName_Click()
    'Check the users permission
    If Me.permissionLevel <> "Manager" Then
        allowCompact = True
    Else
        allowCompact = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Then finally on the Final form's close event you can use.

```
Private Sub Form_Close(Cancel As Integer)
    If allowCompact Then _
        CompactDB
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion of using an automatically opened, hidden form.
I understand the concept of a "Universal Flag"? What's the best way to implement this in Access. As a custom document property?  (In Access2010 menu File - Info - View and edit database properties - Custom)?  Or is there a better way to define it?

Comment: When I said "Universal Flag", what I meat was a Public variable as I have mentioned in my sample coding. Just in a standard module. This should be fine.